# How to mantain files in Heroku that are not in git repo after a deploy

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

This is the scenario: my Node.js app creates a file on the server that stores all user data (nothing sensitive) in a file called `database.json`.

I currently have two environments:

- my local machine, with a `database.json`,
- and my production environment on Heroku, with its own `database.json`

Every time I push a new version of my app, from my machine to production, I would *not* like to replace the production `database.json` file with the one I have in my machine. For that, I used the `.gitignore` to ignore this file, so this file is *not* on GitHub, because it is created within the app execution

But every time I push a new version to Heroku, instead of keeping the old `database.json` file, Heroku erases it. It looks like Heroku completely overwrites all the app folder with the one downloaded from Git instead of "merging" with what is already there.

How can I set up a file on Heroku that I can use to save user data that is *not* affected by `git push`es and deploys?

Comment: There might be some configuration in the deployment script to create a file databse.json while deployment

Comment: the thing is that i dont want to create a new file on deploy, i want to keep the file that is already there that is not in the git repo

Comment: can you check the .gitignore file and make sure this file is listed in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I set up a file on Heroku that I can use to save user data that is *not* affected by `git push`es and deploys?

You can't.

Furthermore, this isn't just about deploys: your file will be lost at other times too.

Your file isn't being overwritten by *Git*; Heroku's [filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Any changes made to it will be lost any time the dyno restarts. This [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting) (at least once per day) whether you deploy or not.

You will need to change how you're persisting data. I suggest using a [real client-server database](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores), but you could also save your file in [third-party object storage using something like Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) or [Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/).